Get the decimal value from $1-\cos(1)$ after Integration
Calculate the given integral. Answer with three digit length.
$$\int_{0}^{1} \sin x \,dx$$
Attempt:
$\int_{0}^{1} \sin x \,dx =\left[-\cos x\right]_0^1$
$= F(1)-F(0)$
$-\cos(1)-(-\cos(0))$
$-\cos(1)+1$
$1-\cos(1)$
My result: $1-\cos(1)$
According to the book: $0,460$.
Note: Typing this on my TI-84 Plus does not give me this, instead a number formatted with Scientific notation.

What number did you get on your calculator? Is your calculator in radians or degrees?

Yeah, seems likely you took $1$ as degrees.

N.B.: $1-\cos\tfrac{\pi}{180}\approx 1.5230\times 10^{-4}$

@JimmyK4542 Degrees.

@ThomasAndrews Please explain

In particular, it is easy to show the $\frac12<\cos(1)<\frac{13}{24}.$

@JimmyK4542 Yep, that did the trick. Radians.

Do you know that there are different  units for angles? The usual first measure you learn are degrees. But mathematicians prefer radians, and all the integral formulas you've learned assume radians.  Calculators usually have two modes for their trig functions, DEG and RAD. You want RAD

Yes. Just that I forget to change the Mode on calculator.

$$\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^4}{8!}+\dots$$
Then $$cos(1)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24}+\dots$$ The next terms are so small that it would not really contribute in an approximation .
$$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24}\approx1-0.5+0.04\approx 0,54\approx \cos(1)$$
So $1-\cos(1)\approx1-0,54\approx 0.46$

Thanks a lot for this. Setting the calculator to Radian from Degree did the trick. But, I truly appreciate this as well.
